# automate app_offline.htm file in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

I want to delete the app_offline page(app_offline.htm) from the root of the IIS application when the work completed.How to automate this deploy and delete the app offline page in iis directory.

I tried read some artciles about MSdeploy but could not get that .
Can we do it by running some commands to auto deploy and delete the app_offline page from the server root directory ?

Please help me on this. I found below two commands to run

```
msdeploy.exe –verb:sync
         -source:contentPath="[Project folder]\App_offline.template.htm"
         -dest:contentPath="[IIS application path]/App_offline.htm",
          computerName="[Destination web server]"
```

for delete

```
msdeploy.exe –verb:delete
         -dest:contentPath="[IIS application path]/App_offline.htm",
          computerName="[Destination web server]"
```

But not get how to run the above commands

Answer (score 0):

You can also try use cmd.exe, It is located at `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, more information you can refer to this link: [Web Deploy (MSDeploy)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/web-deploy-msdeploy-how-to-sync-a-folder).

Comment: When I am running the exe , the window is not coming to write commands

Comment: I re-edited my answer, hope this helps you. [The result is shown in the image](http://sedodream.com/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/MSDeploy-how-to-sync-a-folder_11057/SNAGHTML204f5cd.png).